# How much speed is maintained in a 90 degree turn?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, speed, centrifugal-force

How much speed is maintained in a 90 degree turn? Is there an equation for this? I was recently driving and took a 90 degree turn while coasting at 25 mph and it did not seem like I lost very much speed. Which made me wonder what the equation was for this, does it depend on the momentum of the object?

Answer (score 1):

Here what i think from a layman's point of view

> Let us assume that you were driving your car in an ideal situation that is their is no friction or any other force to reduce your velocity. So when you make a turn or change the direction of the velocity of the car you apply a force on the car to do this, it should be an external force, so when you apply the force to do this the direction of the velocity of the car changes, but their is no change in the speed of the car. However in your case the decrease in the speed of the car was due to friction force between tires and roads and various other forces acting on it from the surrounding and due to the fact that the power to drive the car and turn the car was apllied from same power source however i am not sure about my last line.